# Importing OpenCV in Android Eclipse Project

Tags: android, image, mobile, opencv, compare

I have a rather simple question. I built the OpenCV library with the help of MacPorts. All the files are in my opt directory as they should be. I'd like to use the libopencv_core.2.2.0.dylib in my Android project in Eclipse. There is a method cvnorm() in that library which I want to use. I'm writing a simple little Android app which will need to use some of the methods from OpenCV. I can't seem to add this library to the project, it says it's invalid file type. Would appreciate any help you could give. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There is a special OpenCV trunk for Android. Try [this](http://opencv.itseez.com/doc/tutorials/introduction/android_binary_package/android_binary_package.html) tutorial.

Even it's written for Windows, it worked like a charm in my MacBook Air.